# Subdomain takes the position of main site in Google search result

Tags: seo, google-search, subdomain

We have one domain and one sub-domain. Until last week both of them appear in first page of Google search for very important keyword. Unfortunately Google dropped our main domain from search results. our main site has been in first page for 5 years!

About one year ago we build this sub-domain. It simply has been redirected to one of pages of main domain.

For solving problem we upload a independent site for sub-domain because we guessed that Google think this is our main page of our site. But problem did not solved.

What should we do? our main site offer main services and we we want that will be on first page.

Shout down sub-domain? Redirect to main site? Put the link of our main site in sub-domain? (About one year ago we put link of this sub-domain to our main site. Google indexed it and continuously bring that to top.)
changing in *robots.txt*
....

Comment: Does the subdomain contain the same content, different content, or similar content to the main domain?

Comment: What was the purpose of the sub-domain? Is it still needed?

Comment: @JohnConde both of them have similar content but not same content. The sub-domain only has one page and sort of advertising content that bring customers to main services.

Comment: @closetnoc we also need that subdomain because of advertising content and other pupolar keyword. problem is that overall search appearence of subdomain is better now!

Comment: How is it different from the parent domain name content?

Comment: @closetnoc The sub-domain offer only one free  online service. We designed it for "free [...]" keyword. it has a few text. We advertise our main services in it. Now we  gain well traffic from subdomain to main main site but we do not like to known as "free [...]" instead of professional services.

Comment: I sounds like you did exactly the right thing creating the sub-domain with excellent SEO. Clearly, that worked. Perhaps you can do the same for your professional services. Otherwise, you can lean out and SEO your parent site to compete. Have you thought about another competitive sub-domain for your professional services? Is that a good idea or am I not considering something obvious?

Comment: @closetnoc you give me intresting idea about creating another sub-domain. I think we should redesign the content of our main site (May be smaller size of word and use the better keyword) and send it again to crawler. If does not work, must create another sub-domain. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The demotion of your home page for a specific keyword can be due to link building using that keyword as anchor text and keyword stuffing.   This type of "overoptimization penalty" can cause another page on your site to show up in the search results (but usually lower).

Reference: [A close look at what over optimization really is Google SEO News and Discussion forum at WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4442234.htm)